# Unable to register extension "sandbox" as extensions have already been initialized

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I have a problem installing Sonata project demo. After following [this](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox)...

I get the following problem:

```
Unable to register extension "sandbox" as extensions have already been initialized.

  in /var/www/nfq/sandbox/sonata-sandbox/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php line 627
at Twig_Environment->addExtension(object(Twig_Extension_Sandbox))
  in /var/www/nfq/sandbox/sonata-sandbox/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 7111
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSonata_Formatter_Twig_Env_MarkdownService()
  in /var/www/nfq/sandbox/sonata-sandbox/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 211
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Sonata Formatter, I've the same problem, so I just commented the line who imports its configurations from config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: fos_user.yml }

# Sonata Bundles
- { resource: sonata/sonata_admin.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_block.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_media.yml }
#- { resource: sonata/sonata_formatter.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_news.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_cache.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_seo.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_notification.yml }
- { resource: sonata/sonata_user.yml }
```

**Edit:**

Put this in required libraries in **composer.json**:

```
"twig/twig": "1.11.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can follow the formatter bundle config setting

```
sonata_formatter:
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions: []

        text:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.text
            extensions: []

        twig:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
            extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions
```

more at the sonata site 
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/installation.html